# Efficient pixel manipulation on Windows Phone: should I use XNA?

Tags: performance, algorithm, windows-phone-7, gpu, image-manipulation

I've implemented an image manipulation process on a Windows Phone 7 application that takes a grayscale image (or better, a byte array) and makes some "getPixel/putPixel" operations also using a mask. So, assuming that the algorithm is the most efficient ever, I'm however into a speed optimization problem because of a lot of read/write operations on that byte array.

Hence, I was thinking to move the workload from the CPU to the GPU of the cellphone. First of all, will it give me some performance gains? For a better understanding, think about I'm implementing a median filter, that visits every pixel and its neighbours and puts a new value to the center pixel. Is it a smart move to run this 2D filter from a GPU or is it a waste of time? Does will change something in terms of read/write memory access?

Second, the application is a classic XAML form with a C# code behind. Should I use XNA for this? How can I call its APIs from a non-game scenario?